# Non-Toxic Wood Glue

Tags: wood, glue

I've got a cutting board that was left soaking for too long, and it subsequently cracked and split. Is there a non-toxic wood glue I can use to glue it back together? I'm planning on using a quick clamp and whatever type of wood glue is safe to use for food prep surfaces, if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.benchnotes.com/Cutting%20Boards%20folder/cutting_boards.htm) regular old TiteBond II is non-toxic and FDA approved for cutting boards.

Answer (score 4):

Tightbond II is an excellent choice, but it's not waterproof, and it softens considerably under heat.  TightBond III has much better heat and water resistance.  If there's any chance that somebody will put your cutting boards in a dishwasher, I'd spring the extra two bucks for the TightBond III.

Comment: Looks like II is water resistant, and III is waterproof. It's a huuuuuge cutting board (maybe falls under the chopping block category), so I don't think it's ever in danger of being put in the dishwasher.